# Reading from the keyboard and inserting into an array using EOF

Tags: c

I'm trying to read from the keyboard until EOF, and insert each value into an array.

As simple as that sounds, for some reason, the elements don't get pushed into an array and I don't know why.

Can anybody help me understand what's going on?

Thanks.

```
void tipD(int dim)
{
    long double distanta, timpOdihna;
    long double distantaVec[100], timpOdihnaVec[100];
    while (scanf("%Lf%Lf", &distanta, &timpOdihna) != EOF)
    {
        int i = 0;
        distantaVec[i] = distanta;
        timpOdihnaVec[i++] = timpOdihna;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        printf("%Lf %Lf\n", distantaVec[i], timpOdihnaVec[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice is to read stdin with fgets, then parse line by line and load the array, until some line with eof tag.

Comment: Several errors. `int i = 0;` that resets the index to `0` for **every** iteration - fix by declaring and initialising `i` **outside** the loop. Don't check for `EOF` - check for the number of matches instead, which is `2` in this case.

Comment: Another problem is that the second loop should not use `dim` but should instead use the actual number of successful `scanf` calls which is `i` (after fixing previous comment issues).

Comment: @kaylum I have no idea how I didn't realise that int i=0 is inside the loop. Sorry. Great answer - you can post it so I can accept it:)